# From checkbox list get those ones that were changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a checkbox list like

```
<input checked="checked" class="inv_doc_ids[]" id="inv_doc_ids" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056001">

<input checked="checked" class="inv_doc_ids[]" id="inv_doc_ids" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056002">

<input checked="checked" class="inv_doc_ids[]" id="inv_doc_ids" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056003">
```

I need to check which checkboxes were changed(checked => unchecked, unchecked => checked), and collect those values.

I've stopped at this point now:

```
var collectID = [];
    $.each($("input[class='inv_doc_ids[]']:checked"), function () {
                collectID.push($(this).val());
            });
            console.log(collectID);
```

It collects only those checkboxes that are checked and returns their values in array => `[01000290056001, 01000290056002, 01000290056003]`

What do I need to add in order to make it work correctly?
Thought about to add something like this:

```
var show = $(this),
                    colllect = (input.attr("checked") || "") === "checked";
return (colllect !== input.attr("checked"));
```

But don't know if it is the right way.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to know which checkboxes have been changed compared to their values when the *page was loaded* - is that right?

Comment: `attr('checked') !== undefined` would tell you if it had the attribute on the element at all in the original source

Comment: First problem. You're using the same id multiple times...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, you're right. Page has been loaded => You check/uncheck checkboxes and get values from checkboxes that have been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select those that have a checked attribute that are not checked, and those that do not have a checked attribute that are checked.

```js
$('button').on('click', e => {
  console.log(
    $('input[checked]:not(:checked), input:not([checked]):checked')
    .map( ( _, it ) => [[ it.value, it.checked ? 1 : 0 ]] )
    .get()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056001">
<input checked class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056002">
<input checked class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056003">
<br>
<input class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056004">
<input class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056005">
<input class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056006">
<br>
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your help, it works as I expected. 1 more question, is there any way to pass 1 more value based on its checked/unchecked status? Like: if checked => unchecked, then array would be `[value, 0]`, if unchecked => checked, then array would be `[value, 1]`. Is that possible?

Comment: `.map( ( _, it ) => [ it.value, it.checked ? 1 : 0 ] )` should do the trick @Marshmello

Comment: Yes! Thank you! And the last question. I'm using RoR on back/front end. When im passing values, im getting 1 array => `[value, 0, value, value, 0]`. How to pass it correctly from js to do smth like this => `[[value, 0], [value, 0]]` ? I've a little bit 'updated' the script from my side, using the "push" function now, to pass all values: https://pastebin.com/bUk50fTi JS not my strong side, so thank you for your help!

Comment: @Marshmello updated the answer to return the array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event listener to handle when the checkbox change event fires.  Then add these values to an array when the checkbox is clicked.

```js
// array to hold modified checkbox values
var checkboxes = [];

// event listener on change
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    checkboxes.push($(this).val());
});

// log values to console
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){ 
    console.log(checkboxes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input checked="checked" class="inv_doc_ids[]" id="inv_doc_ids" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056001">

<input checked="checked" class="inv_doc_ids[]" id="inv_doc_ids" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056002">

<input  class="inv_doc_ids[]" id="inv_doc_ids" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056003">

<button id="btn1" >Show modified values</button>
```

PS: I'd advise to have different IDs for each checkbox.  Html IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` to know which one is change.?

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function(item){
   item.addEventListener('change', function(){
      console.log(item.value); 
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var valuelist = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        var dom_checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        if ((dom_checked === "checked" && checked === false) ||
           typeof dom_checked === "undefined" && checked === true) {
            valuelist.push(this.value);
        }  
    })
    console.log(valuelist);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056001">
<input checked class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056002">
<input checked class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056003">
<input class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056004">
<input class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056005">
<input checked class="inv_doc_ids[]" name="inv_doc_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="01000290056006">
<button>Check</button>
```